# Some of the methods are working but not all of them

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Js and I am having trouble with the code. The problem is that when I multiply different methods together the program does not work. However, some of the methods are are working even though they are kind of identical. The other problem is that I have to change the first selection first and then the other to get the total I need. I want to get a total that changes whenever I choose any selection from the drop box regardless of ordering. I know I am foreseeing a mistake here or simply cant understand. Please feel free to point out my mistakes and help me better my code because I know its more complicated than it should be. Thank you for your help.

HTML

```
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scriptt.js "></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="hideTotal()">
    <form method="POST" class="device"/>
      <center class="all" >
        <div class= "data">
          <label class="req">Select The Device</label>
          <select  class="mydevice" id= "selectDevice" onChange="calculateTotal()">
            <option> None </option>
            <option  value="100" id='lg'> LG X CHARGE </option>
            <option  value="129"> ZTE MAX XL </option>
            <option  value="123"> LG DYNASTY </option>
            <option  value="400"> LG TRIBUTE </option>
          </select>

          <label for="For" class="req"> For </label>
          <select class="mydevice" id="port" onChange="calculateTotal()">
            <option id= 'none' value='none'> None </option>
            <option  id='port' value="129" >Port-In</option>
            <option class="upgrade">Upgrade</option>
            <option class="newAct">New Activation</option>

          </select>

        <label for="Plan" class="req">Plan</label>
          <select class="plan" id='plan' onChange="calculatedToral()">
            <option>None</option>
            <option value="35" >$35 plan</option>
            <option value="50">$50 plan</option>
            <option value="60">$60 plan</option>
          </select>

          <div class="access" >
            <label for="phoneInsurance"> Phone Insurance </label>
            <select class="myinsurance" id='insurance'  onChange="calculatedToral()">
              <option>None</option>
              <option value="7">Yes</option>
            </select>

          <label for="phoneCase"> Phone Case </label>
          <select class="mycases" id='case' onChange="calculatedToral()">
            <option>None</option>
            <option value="25">Regular</option>
            <option value="35">Wallet</option>
          </select>

          <label for="screenProtector"> Screen Protector </label>
          <select class="myscreen" id='screen' onChange="calculatedToral()">
            <option value="15">Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
          </select>

        <center>
          <div id="total"></div>
```

Js

```
var device_prices = new Array();
device_prices["100"]=100;
device_prices["129"]=129;
device_prices["123"]=123;
device_prices["400"]=400;

var port_prices = new Array();
port_prices["129"]=0.097;

var plan_prices = new Array();
plan_prices["35"]=35;
plan_prices["50"]=50;
plan_prices["60"]=60;

var insurance_prices = new Array();
inusrance_prices["7"]=7;

var phone_case = new Array();
phone_case["25"] = 25;
phone_case["30"] = 30;

var screen_protector = new Array();
screen_protector["15"] = 15;

function getDevicePrice() {
    var deviceSelect = document.getElementById('selectDevice');
    //alert(device_prices[deviceSelect.value]);
    return device_prices[deviceSelect.value];
}

function getPortPrice() {
    var portSelect = document.getElementById('port');
    return port_prices[portSelect.value];
}

function getPlanPrice() {
    var planSelected = document.getElementById('plan');
    return plan_prices[planSelected.value];
}

function getInsurancePrice() {
    var insurancee = document.getElementById('insurance');
    return insurance_prices[insurancee.value];
}
function getCasePrice() {
    var caseSelect = document.getElementById('case');
    return phone_case[caseSelect.value];
}
function getScreenPrice() {
    var screenSelect = document.getElementById('screen');
    return screen_protector[screenSelect.value];
}

function calculateTotal() {
        var total = getDevicePrice()*getPlanPrice()*getPortPrice();
        total = total.toFixed(2);
        var totalEl = document.getElementById('total');

        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Your Total is: $" +        total;

        totalEl.style.display = 'block';

}

function hideTotal() {
    var totalEl = document.getElementById('total');
    totalEl.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Comment: I see following typo in you html code, <select class="plan" id='plan' onChange="calculatedToral()">,
I believe this should be calculateTotal()

Comment: What if you return `0` from the get-functions if the element value is empty. I can imagine that it's the calculation that goes wrong when the value is missing.

Comment: You would be surprised to know that code `var a = new Array(); a[100] = 100;` will actually create 101 entries in that array and 100 of them will have a value of undefined.

Comment: What is the best way to avoid the 100 undefined values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**spelling**
var insurance_prices = new Array();
inusrance_prices["7"]=7;

**funtion or method not define**
calculatedToral

```
var device_prices = new Array();
device_prices["100"]=100;
device_prices["129"]=129;
device_prices["123"]=123;
device_prices["400"]=400;

var port_prices = new Array();
port_prices["129"]=0.097;

var plan_prices = new Array();
plan_prices["35"]=35;
plan_prices["50"]=50;
plan_prices["60"]=60;

var insurance_prices = new Array();
insurance_prices["7"]=7;

var phone_case = new Array();
phone_case["25"] = 25;
phone_case["30"] = 30;

var screen_protector = new Array();
screen_protector["15"] = 15;

function getDevicePrice() {
    var deviceSelect = document.getElementById('selectDevice');
    //alert(device_prices[deviceSelect.value]);
    alert("1");
    return device_prices[deviceSelect.value];

}

function getPortPrice() {
    var portSelect = document.getElementById('port');
    alert("2")
    return port_prices[portSelect.value];
}

function getPlanPrice() {
    var planSelected = document.getElementById('plan');
    alert("3")
    return plan_prices[planSelected.value];
}

function getInsurancePrice() {
alert("4")
    var insurancee = document.getElementById('insurance');
    return insurance_prices[insurancee.value];
}
function getCasePrice() {
alert("5")
    var caseSelect = document.getElementById('case');
    return phone_case[caseSelect.value];
}
function getScreenPrice() {
alert("6")
    var screenSelect = document.getElementById('screen');
    return screen_protector[screenSelect.value];
}

function calculateTotal() {
alert("7")
        var total = getDevicePrice()*getPlanPrice()*getPortPrice();
        total = total.toFixed(2);
        var totalEl = document.getElementById('total');

        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = "Your Total is: $" +        total;

        totalEl.style.display = 'block';

}
function calculatedToral()

{
alert("8")
}
function hideTotal() {
alert("9")
    var totalEl = document.getElementById('total');
    totalEl.style.display = 'none';
    }
```

i was corrected your all function or method of your JavaScript and all are working (i was add alert() for function check). check calculation errors yourself

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It was so dumb of me to foresee this mistake. I did get to run, but the problem I am having right not is that when change other selection. The total does not change unless I change the first selection. How can avoid that? How can I change the total whenever I change any of the selection? and After I select the first one the Total is NAN unless I select other selections and then change the first selection.

Comment: @Beel your question puzzler can you explain me clear what do you want . according to your problem you don't want perform any operation on first drop down control. after complete selection or two or more selection then show output i am right.

Comment: I figured out the problem. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The JS calls in your HTML tags have wrong names.

Eg: You've `calculatedToral()` instead of `calculatedTotal()`in the following:

```
<select class="myinsurance" id='insurance'  onChange="calculatedToral()">
    <option>None</option>
    <option value="7">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Check all the names properly.

### **Also, some footnotes since you're a beginner:**

- Try to avoid inline scripting. (look at [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting)) I.e., as far as possible, don't mix the javascript event calls (like `onChange(), onClick()`) in the HTML tags. It'll make the code difficult to read and change in future.
- Instead of inline scripting, try to put all Javascript either within the `<script>` tags (at end of page is usually better). Use `.getElementsByClass()` for wider control and `.getElementById()` for  granular control of events.
- Also, since you're using jQuery, include the `<script>` calling the jQuery CDN at the end, just before `</body>`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will keep that in mind when I am optimizing the code.